# Sonar properties files

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have a project that has the following package structure

```
src/main/proj
    -com.company.package
        -appName
            -morepackages

        -appVersion2
            -morepackages

sonar-runner.properties
sonarBuild.sh
sonar-runner-project2.properties
sonarBuildProject2.sh
```

As it stands, with the default properties file i can run the sonar report and it will generate a review for the whole project

```bash
sonar.projectKey=KEY
sonar.projectName=PROJNAME
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.host.url=someurl

#Path for sonar sources
sonar.sources=src/main/java

#Path for libraries
sonar.libraries=target/lib/*.jar

#Path for binaries
sonar.binaries=target/classes

#--------Default database
sonar.jdbc.url=someurl
sonar.jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

#----- Global database settings
sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
sonar.jdbc.password=sonar

#----- Default directory layout
sonar.java.source=1.6
sonar.java.target=1.6

sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Ideally however I would like to separate the two reports so i have one for the original package and one for the appVersion2 package. Now - as mentioned above I have created a separate properties file for each. Should i just point `sonar.sources` to the respective packages for each job to analyse or is there a better way to do this all in one property file?

Thanks

***EDIT***

My multi module attempt properties file looks as follows

```bash
sonar.projectKey=rootkey
sonar.projectName=rootname
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.host.url=rooturl
sonar.sources=src/main/java/
sonar.libraries=target/lib/*.jar
sonar.modules=module1,module2
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

#----- Global database settings
sonar.jdbc.username=user
sonar.jdbc.password=pass

sonar.java.source=1.7
sonar.java.target=1.7


#--------Default database
sonar.jdbc.url=url
sonar.jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver


module1.sonar.projectName=proja
module2.sonar.projectName=projb

module1.sonar.projectKey=projakey
module2.sonar.projectKey=projbkey

#Path for sonar sources
module1.sonar.sources=src/main/java/app1code
module2.sonar.sources=src/main/java/app2code

#Path for binaries
module1.sonar.binaries=target/classes/app1binaries
module2.sonar.binaries=target/classes/app2binaries
```

I get an error in the output saying....

```bash
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.RunnerException: org.sonar.runner.RunnerException: The base directory of the module 'module1' does not exist: patthtoapp/module1
    at org.sonar.runner.Runner.delegateExecution(Runner.java:288)
    at org.sonar.runner.Runner.execute(Runner.java:151)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:84)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:56)
Caused by: org.sonar.runner.RunnerException: The base directory of the module 'module1' does not exist: pathtoapp/module1
    at org.sonar.runner.internal.batch.SonarProjectBuilder.setProjectBaseDir(SonarProjectBuilder.java:279)
    at org.sonar.runner.internal.batch.SonarProjectBuilder.loadChildProject(SonarProjectBuilder.java:191)
    at org.sonar.runner.internal.batch.SonarProjectBuilder.defineChildren(SonarProjectBuilder.java:169)
    at org.sonar.runner.internal.batch.SonarProjectBuilder.generateProjectDefinition(SonarProjectBuilder.java:122)
    at org.sonar.runner.internal.batch.Launcher.execute(Launcher.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.sonar.runner.Runner.delegateExecution(Runner.java:285)
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have to specify the `projectBaseDir` if the module name doesn't match you module directory.

Since both your module are located in ".", you can simply add the following to your sonar-project properties:

```
module1.sonar.projectBaseDir=.
module2.sonar.projectBaseDir=.
```

Sonar will handle your modules as components of the project:

[image: Result of Sonar analysis]

**EDIT**

If both of your modules are located in the same source directory, define the same source folder for both and exclude the unwanted packages with `sonar.exclusions`:

```
module1.sonar.sources=src/main/java
module1.sonar.exclusions=app2code/**/*

module2.sonar.sources=src/main/java
module2.sonar.exclusions=app1code/**/*
```

[More details about file exclusion](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-patterns)

Comment: this approach leads to a new error = Caused by: org.sonar.squid.api.AnalysisException: Got an exception - org.sonar.squid.api.AnalysisException: The source directory does not correspond to the package declaration com.company.package, file : pathtofile/myclass.java, line : 0

Comment: If your modules sources are in the same folder, try specifying the correct source folder for both modules and excludes the unwanted package with 'sonar.exclusions'.

Comment: I edited my answer to address the AnalysisException.

Comment: just trying it out now - project takes a while to build :p

Answer (score 4):

You can define a [Multi-module project structure](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Runner#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeRunner-Multi-moduleProject), then you can set the configuration for sonar in one properties file in the root folder of your project, (`Way #1`)

Comment: this is exactly what i have tried - please see edit and problems after trying that approach

Answer (score 0):

Do the build job on Jenkins first without Sonar configured. Then add Sonar, and run a build job again. Should fix the problem