# Gradle - Jacoco - SonarQube programmatically set project root directories

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, jacoco

Pursuant to this question: [Project exclude with gradle / sonar / Jacoco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36850833/project-exclude-with-gradle-sonar-jacoco)

Using Gradle, how can I programmatically access the sonar project base directory? I want to do this in subprojects so that I don't have to mess with it for each project. We have a really large build with 90+ subprojects.