# Setup Sonar properties files for multiple projects

Tags: sonarqube

I want to analyze multiple projects,and I would like to separate the two reports so i have one for the CA_Report package and one for the CallCenter package.I had tried the solutions from [Setup sonar-runner for multiple java projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487602/setup-sonar-runner-for-multiple-java-projects)
 and [Sonar properties files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21934591/sonar-properties-files)
 I tried to using sonar-project.properties to solve the following error,but it doesn't work with my following cmd.

**Cmd**

> CD /D D:\trunk
>       SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"myProject" /n:"myProject" /v:"1.0"
>       "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /t:Rebuild

**Error**
MSBUILD : error MSB1003:Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.

**I have a project that has the following package structure**

```
-trunk(folder with sonar-project.properties)  
    -Center   
        -CA_Report(folder with source files)  
            -CA_Report.sln
        -CallCenter(folder with source files)  
            -RBSolution.sln   
    -sonar-project.properties
```

**My sonar-project.properties file looks as follows**

```
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.projectKey=FubonLifeCallCenterConfigureTest
sonar.projectName=FubonLifeCallCenterConfigureTest
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=trunk/Center/CA_Report,trunk/Center/CallCenter
sonar.projectBaseDir=D:\\FubonLife\\trunk\\Center

sonar.modules=CA_Report,CallCenter
CA_Report.sonar.projectBaseDir=D:\\FubonLife\\trunk\\Center\\CA_Report
CA_Report.projectKey=CA_Report
CA_Report.projectName=CA_Report
CA_Report.sources=trunk/Center/CA_Report

CallCenter.sonar.projectBaseDir=D:\\FubonLife\\trunk\\Center\\CallCenter
CallCenter.projectKey=CallCenter
CallCenter.projectName=CallCenter
CallCenter.sources=trunk/Center/CallCenter
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate "it doesn't work" means for you ? What happens ? Can you share screenshots, logs, etc. ?

Comment: @Julien L. - SonarSource Team , I edit the question, thx.

Comment: I still don't see any errors...

Comment: @Julien L. - SonarSource Team, sorry I added the error log.