# How do I add Sonarqube scans to NativeScript apps?

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, nativescript-angular

Has anyone ever integrated Sonarqube scans in their CI pipeline to scan Nativescript apps?

My current scenario is I have 3 separate build jobs.

### On-Premise

Build the Angular website

### Cloud - Windows

Build the android apk and publish the artifact (tns build android...)

### Cloud - Mac

Build the ios ipa and publish the artifact (tns build ios)

The problem I face is that I want to run a sonarqube scan, which needs to run on-premise, which is fine because I can download the artifacts (apk file or ipa), or I can download the source. The real issue is that I do now know what to scan exactly. I don't know what to put in my sonar.properties (sonar.sources). Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sonar.sources paths are the directories containing main source files. The path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Defaults to `.`.

So you can download the source code, and set the path of `sonar.sources` to the source code folder.

For example, if the source files reside in `mysource` folder which is in the same directory of your sonar.properties file. You can set the `sonar.sources=mysource`.

Please check the document
[Analysis Parameters](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/analysis-parameters/) and
[SonarScanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner/) for more information.

You can also check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21934591/sonar-properties-files), you may find it helpful.

You can also check out this tutorial to integrate Sonarque with azure devops pipeline. [Managing technical debt with SonarQube and Azure DevOps](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/sonarqube/)

Comment: I had all this done already, but my question was more centred around Nativescript apps specifically. I didn't know which folders in my source code I had to set sonar.sources to. I was able to figure it out with the help of a dev lead. I just wasn't sure which files I had to set exactly.